# TextView display wrong with escape character

Tags: android, textview

I have a random message that contains escape characters. I found that TextView displays wrong spaces for escape characters `"\t"`.

My sample project has an Activity that has a layout with only one TextView.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_hello"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_hello"
        android:maxLines="5"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

I define text in file `strings.xml`

```
<string name="text_hello">Click Change: 13894\t18258\nClick Change: 1604\t2190\nClick Change: 9250\t11962</string>
```

The corresponding result is

[image]

I change the text like below

```
<string name="text_hello">ABC: 13894\t18258\nDEF: 1604\t2190\nXYZ: 9250\t11962</string>
```

The corresponding result will changes
[image]

As sample, TextView displays wrongly space. Can anyone has a solution to fix this issue?

Comment: `TextView displays wrongly space` because your `DEF` & `XYZ` has 4 digit number in starting while in `ABC` you have 5 digits\

Comment: @NileshRathod: why DEF & XYZ with 4 starting digit numbers don't display '\t'

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
\u0020
```

or

```
&#032;
```

instead of `\t` in string.xml file.